# docker rabbitmq how to expose port and reuse container with a docker file

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

Hi I am finding it very confusing how I can create a docker file that would run a rabbitmq container, where I can expose the port so I can navigate to the management console via localhost and a port number.

I see someone has provided this dockerfile example, but unsure how to run it?

```
version: "3"
services:
 rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
     volumes:
      - "rabbitmq_data:/data"
     volumes:
      rabbitmq_data:
```

I have got rabbit working locally fine, but everyone tells me docker is the future, at this rate I dont get it.

Does the above look like a valid way to run a rabbitmq container? where can I find a full understandable example?

1. Do I need a docker file or am I misunderstanding it?
2. How can I specify the port? in the example above what are first numbers 5672:5672 and what are the last ones?
3. How can I be sure that when I run the container again, say after a machine restart that I get the same container?

Many thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Docker-compose

What you posted is not a **Dockerfile**. It is a **docker-compose** file.

To run that, you need to

1) Create a file called *docker-compose.yml* and paste the following inside:

```
version: "3"
services:
 rabbitmq:
  image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
  volumes:
    - "rabbitmq_data:/data"
volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
```

2) Download docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

3) (Re-)start Docker.

4) On a console run:

```
cd <location of docker-compose.yml>
docker-compose up
```

### Do I need a docker file or am I misunderstanding it?

You have a docker-compose file. The `rabbitmq:3-management` is the Docker image built using the RabbitMQ Dockerfile (which you **don't** need. The image will be downloaded the first time you run `docker-compose up`.

### How can I specify the port? In the example above what are the first numbers 5672:5672 and what are the last ones?

`"5672:5672"` specifies the port of the queue.

`"15672:15672"` specifies the port of the management plugin.

The numbers on the left-hand-side are the ports you can access from outside of the container. So, if you want to work with different ports, change the ones on the **left**. The right ones are defined internally.

This means you can access the management plugin after at `http:\\localhost:15672` (or more generically `http:\\<host-ip>:<port exposed linked to 15672>`).

You can see more info on the RabbitMQ Image on the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/).

### How can I be sure that when I rerun the container, say after a machine restart that I get the same container?

I assume you want the same container because you want to persist the data. You can use `docker-compose stop` restart your machine, then run `docker-compose start`. Then the same container is used. However, if the container is ever deleted you lose the data inside it.

That is why you are using [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). The data collected in your container gets also stored in your host machine. So, if you remove your container and start a *new* one, the data is still there because it was stored in the host machine.

Comment: Wow that's a good answer on all the levels, thank you very much, amazingly helpful cheers.

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)